# Spring Boot + Bootstrap + Thymeleaf Radio Button

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have this piece of code in my Thymeleaf template:

```
<form action="#"
      th:action="@{/update/{id}(id=${user.id})}"
      th:object="${user}"
      method="post"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">

 <tr th:each="pic: ${pics}" >
                        <td class="col_name" >
                            <div class="box small">
                                <img th:src="'pics/' + ${user.id} + '/' + ${pic}"/>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="col_actions">
                            <a style="color:#808080; margin-right: 10px;">
                                <input type="radio" th:field="*{mainPicture}" th:value="${pic}" >Main picture<br>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td class="col_actions">
                            <a href="#" style="color:#808080;  text-align: center;"  >
                                <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

checking the source code:

```
<td class="col_actions">
                            <a style="color:#808080; margin-right: 10px;">
                                <input type="radio" value="7e7f6887-c0ce-4dc3-bb95-2b9ef92fc903.jpg" id="mainPicture1" name="mainPicture" >Main picture<br>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td class="col_actions">
                            <a href="#" style="color:#808080;  text-align: center;"  >
                                <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr >
                        <td class="col_name" >
                            <div class="box small">
                                <img src="pics/5/7e92cc5c-73e7-451b-9ee8-2ae43c1b0125.jpg"/>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="col_actions">
                            <a style="color:#808080; margin-right: 10px;">
                                <input type="radio" value="7e92cc5c-73e7-451b-9ee8-2ae43c1b0125.jpg" id="mainPicture2" name="mainPicture" >Main picture<br>
                            </a>
                        </td>
```

...

on the controller:

```
@PostMapping("/update/{id}")
    public String updateUser(@PathVariable("id") long id, @Valid UserPayload userPayload,
            BindingResult result, Model model) {


        System.out.println("===================");
        System.out.println( userPayload.getMainPicture());
        System.out.println("===================");

..
}


@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(NON_NULL)
public class UserPayload implements Serializable {

    private Long id;

    // pics
    private System mainPicture;
...
}
```

but is null and in the template I checked id="mainPicture2"

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Or better, what is null that you don't want to be null?

Comment: Please share more context. How `<form>` tag in your template looks like? How a method handling the form in your `@Controller` class looks like? How `UserPayload` class looks like? You act like your question is about Thymeleaf while it's not. Rendered inputs have both name and value - that's all they need. Thymeleaf worked as intended. Unless you provide java code snippets it's impossible to tell where is your mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong type in your `UserPayload` class. Instead of:

```
private System mainPicture;
```

...you should have:

```
private String mainPicture;
```

When you change the type then a value binds properly and `System.out.println( userPayload.getMainPicture());` will print `7e92cc5c-73e7-451b-9ee8-2ae43c1b0125.jpg` intead of `null`.

**Edit:**

I'll expand my answer a bit.

I've assumed [System](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) was mistaken used in place of [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Otherwise e.g. `System` is a class of yours - then your problem is narrowed down to deserialization issue. There is plain text value passed from the form to the controller (i.a. `"7e92cc5c-73e7-451b-9ee8-2ae43c1b0125.jpg"`). Java should know the way how to bind such a text to your `mainPicture` variable. If `mainPicture` is of any custom type of yours then it isn't a simple assignment anymore. Probably a contructor accepting single `String` argument would be enough.